# Can I use the "stream copy" of ffmpeg in OpenCV with VideoWriter class?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, opencv

Python: 3.6, Ubuntu 18.04, OpenCV 4.1.0

I have an IP camera that streams video data in H.264 encoding. I would like to take this video stream and save it in a .avi file using Python without any encoding or decoding. Using a command line interface and ffmpeg commands, this is trivial to do.

```
mycomputer@home:~$ ffmpeg -i rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.1/?framerate=30.0?streamprofile=defaultcameraprofile -acodec copy -vcodec copy output_file_name.avi
```

I'd like to do a similar thing from within Python using OpenCV. Currently, I am using VideoCapture class to read in each frame, and then using the OpenCV VideoWriter class to write this frame to a file. My issue is that the VideoWriter class requires a four_cc code to specify which codec is to  be used during writing, whereas I don't want to use any codec at all (or more precisely, I want to use the stream copy of FFmpeg, but there is to my knowledge no corresponding four_cc code). OpenCV documentation specifies that if I use the FFmpeg backend API and specify both a codec and framerate of 0, the raw stream should be written to the new file. However, when I do this, no file is created.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.1/?framerate=30.0?streamprofile=defaultcameraprofile", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
# output file, backend API, four_cc code integer, framerate, frame size tuple
out = cv2.videoWriter("output_file.avi",cv2.CAP_FFMPEG,0,0,(frame_width,frame_height))
```

I have tried many combinations of other input parameters to the videoWriter constructor but all of them either re-encode the stream or do not write an output file. For instance, I have tried nearly every combination of framerate {0,30}, output file extension {.avi, .mp4, .h264, .mkv, None} and codec {0, "H.264", "RAW ", "DBI ", "    ", "MPEG", "COPY", "NONE"}.

```
out = cv2.videoWriter("output_file.avi",cv2.CAP_FFMPEG,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('H','2','6','4'),30,(frame_width,frame_height))
```

Is it possible to use the FFmpeg stream copy within OpenCV to save video data without encoding it? If not, I will change tact to running shell commands from within Python, but I'd prefer the former approach if feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of additional rooting around, I decided that there probably wasn't a good way to do this using the VideoWriter class in OpenCV. Instead, I used an ffmpeg command line command called using the subprocess module.

```
command = ['ffmpeg', '-i', 'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.1/axis-media/media.amp?framerate=30.0', '-acodec', 'copy', '-vcodec', 'copy', '-r', '30.0', 'output_file.avi']
p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
input("Press Enter to stop capture...")
os.kill(p.pid, 15)
```

Comment: I have used [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) for this and it works well. It's another way to skin this cat if you want to avoid using `subprocess`. BTW I've also resorted to `ffmpeg` for this exact situation, maybe we should add an issue for this in the OpenCV GitHub? I'd prefer to use OpenCV for this if possible.

Comment: Can you add the line of code you'd use in ffmpeg-python for stream copy?  I'll add an issue to the OpenCV repo.

Comment: Thanks @DerekG. Below is the code I use using the bindings from ffmpeg-python. Please update with the issue number so I can follow. 
`
        stream = ffmpeg.input(rtsp_url)
        stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, output_mp4_file,
                               **{"codec:v": "copy",
                                  "rtsp_transport": "tcp",
                                  "y": None
                                  }
                               )
        ffmpeg.run(stream)
`